# Conjunctive types in C#

Tags: c#, types, type-systems

An advantage of generic classes in C# is that one can put constraints on the types so only types who satisfy several constraints are accepted. For instance:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : Bar, IBaz, IFoobar {

    public Foo (T value) {
        //initialize
    }

}
```

This means `T` can only be unified with types who are derived from the three described classes.

When using methods one can make the methods generic as well. I was wondering however why one can't specify such constraint in a constructor. For instance:

```
public class Foo {

    public Foo (Bar & IBaz & IFoobar value) {
        //initialize (the "&" syntax is just an example)
    }

}
```

One can make the class generic, but this can be rather cumbersome if only the constructor will use the `value` and other methods of the class do not depend on `T`. Some problems might even be difficult to resolve with generic classes for instance one needs to write a comparer `SomeComparer<T,Q> : IComparer<Foo<T>,Foo<Q>>` introducing loads of generic classes who are in fact not generic at all.

I don't see why this is not implemented since the type system can easily check if an argument satisfies all type constraints.

What are the arguments not to define conjunctive types in the C# language specifications?

Comment: Most likely: The C# team only has a limited ammount of time, and considers other language improvements more important. However, I do think support for algebraic data types (conjunctions, discriminated unions) could be a valuable addition to C#. By the way, you can work around your constructor example by using a static factory method.

Comment: Yeah, but a factory method introduces more classes. I don't state this is a bad workaround, but I guess conjunctive types are more elegant.

Comment: This question is a bit out of the bounds of StackOverflow. "What are the arguments" make it subjective and difficult to imperially answer.

Comment: @vcsjones: I partially agree. Although some workarounds can be valuable like the one provided by Medo42.

Comment: I'm confused here. Can someone enlighten me as to why you would want to use a generic parameter in a constructor for a class that is not generic? I'm struggling to think of a reasonable scenario. I'm doing my Lippert dance but the inspiration alludes me.

Comment: "the type system can easily check if an argument satisfies all type constraints." - this seems like a huge assumption.

Comment: Say you have for instance a collection of Bar (and you cannot modify the type because it is inherited) but you also want to notify that object, something that is implemented in the IBaz interface, then one can do both without having to worry that the object might not support IBaz. In general: I want to use methods of several interface to register `value`...

Comment: @CommuSoft, the factory method can be a member of the same class, no need to introduce new ones. I'm not talking about the factory pattern, just a simple `static public` method that returns a `Foo`. You'll want to have this method be a member of the class it creates, in fact, so that you can make the constructor private.

Comment: @Gusdor: If the system can do this with generic types, I don't see why it cannot be done by using the "generic" type implicitly.

Comment: @CommuSoft I might be misunderstanding once again, but it sounds like a delicate sprinkling of `dynamic` would do that job.

Comment: @Medo: true, but still you will have to convert the object manually. For instance I want to call some methods of Bar, I can simply use `value.Method1(arguments);` but if I want to call methods from `IBaz`, I will have to write `((IBaz) value).Method2(arg);`. Yeah I know, it's not that much effort, but the type system can perfectly know that the object supports `Method2`.

Comment: @Gusdor: the only problem with `dynamic` - I think - Is that is bypasses static typing...

Comment: @CommuSoft it does - and i greatly dislike solutions that require it.

Comment: @Gusdor: the point is that with the `&` operator defined in the question, static typing is not bypassed. This is a more "safe" solution since the compiler can warn when one uses an object that is not casted to the correct type.

Comment: @CommuSoft if you don't mind the memory overhead, you can just store the same reference in three different fields - one for each interface. I've done it in the past. However, then it it worth considering whether your design isn't over-specific by *requiring* the three interfaces to be implemented by the same object. It might make sense to allow passing three different objects. Whether that makes sense depends on your specific case of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature might be useful, but just hasn't been implemented. The C# team only has so much time, and I suppose this has just never made the cut. There are a lot of things that make this difficult: let's say you have `Foo` and `Foo<T>` classes, and each have non-generic and `Foo<U>` constructors. If you call `new Foo<int>(1)`, is that `Foo..ctor<U>` or `Foo<T>..ctor`? And is `Foo<T>..ctor<U>` referenced by `new Foo<int><string>("")`? It can't be done without introducing some new syntax, and confusing any way I can see it being done, so maybe it's best that generics are not allowed on constructors.

You could work around it by writing a generic method on your non-generic class, e.g.

```
void Main()
{
    Foo foo = Foo.GetInstance(new BarBazAndFoobarImplementer());
}
public sealed class Foo {
    private Foo(Bar value) {
        this.Thing1 = value.BarProperty;
        this.Thing2 = ((IBaz)value).IBazProperty;
        this.Thing3 = ((IFoobar)value).IFoobarProperty;
    }

    public static Foo GetInstance<T>(T value) where T : Bar, IBaz, IFoobar {
        return new Foo(value);
    }
}
```

(this doesn't suffer from the above problem because you could unambiguously call `Foo.GetInstance<U>(..)` and `Foo<T>.GetInstance<U>(..)`)

Answer (score 1):

One way something like this could be done, is to use a private constructor and a factory method:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public static Foo Create<T>(T value) where T : Bar, IBaz, IFoobar
    {
        return new Foo(value);
    }

    private Foo(Bar value)
    {
        // whatever
        // feel free to cast to IBaz or IFoobar as needed
    }
}
```

You can't do that with a constructor, because a constructor is supposed to construct an instance of its type. What would you do with `value`? Store it in a field maybe, but what would the type of the field be?

A better way might be that `Bar`, or a class derived from `Bar` implements both interfaces.

Comment: Say you have for instance a collection of `Bar` (and you cannot modify the type because it is inherited) but you also want to notify that object, something that is implemented in the `IBaz` interface, then one can do both without having to worry that the object might not support `IBaz`...

Comment: @CommuSoft Sure, I see the theoretical value. I'm just not sure that the pratical value is very high. Maybe the C# team felt the same, and they decided to implement another feature instead.